# select from multiple files with the same name in intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a project with ~30 modules. Now I want to open pom.xml file of one of the modules. ctrl-shift-n and typing pom.xml will present me with the list of all pom.xml files. I then need to scroll the list (which is not sorted) to find the file I'm looking for.

Is there a way to open such files with less hassle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also add parts of the path within into the dialog.

e.g.
foo/bar/pom

will show those files:

- foo/bar/pom.xml
- foodir/bardir/pom.xml
- foodir/bardir/pom.old
- otherDir/foodir/bardir/pom.old

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is not much you can do about it right now, it must be addressed in IDEA code. I've submitted a [new issue for this problem](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-57700). Please use the "watch" feature to be notified when it's fixed.

Sorry for the inconvenience.